Why are images zoomed in browsers, and how to circumvent this issue?
Why aren't these images crispy on site (online)? Why are they zoomed in?
Online:  
These also should look crispy, but they are zoomed in:

Here's the comparison:
On the right side of this screenshot, we can somehow see what they should look like:

Download them or open them in a new browser window, and you'll see:  
My screen resolution data:

If it matters, the browser I'm using is Edge, but the same happens in all bowsers I have (including Chrome, Firefox, Opera etc.)
Would I need to convert the pngs into svgs?
Here's my snippet:


#szabvanyossag img {
  border: none;
  width: 80px;
  height: 15px;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
<span id="szabvanyossag">
<a href="https://jigsaw.w3.org/css-validator/check/referer" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JpLU85h2.png" alt="érvényes CSS3!"></a>&nbsp;<a href="https://validator.w3.org/check?uri=referer" target="_blank"><img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JfXymTp2.png" alt="érvényes HTML5!"></a>
</span>




Unless you mean "blurred when zoomed," I see the same thing in a browser as in an image editor with no change in size.

@Nanigashi yes, this is also relevant to me. Thank you.

If you mean blurred when zoomed, CSS image-rendering
From MDN:

auto
The scaling algorithm is UA dependent. Since version 1.9 (Firefox 3.0), Gecko uses bilinear resampling (high quality).
...
crisp-edges
The image is scaled with an algorithm such as "nearest neighbor" that preserves contrast and edges in the image. Generally intended for images such as pixel art or line drawings, no blurring or color smoothing occurs.
...

The default is auto.
In general, it's up to the web author to specify better CSS.
Using the PNGs from the question:


img {
  width: 25%;
}

.crisp img {
  image-rendering: crisp-edges;
}

span {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}
<!DOCTYPE html><html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>79294198</title>
</head><body>
  <div>
    <span>Auto:</span>
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JpLU85h2.png">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JfXymTp2.png">
  </div><div class="crisp">
    <span>Crisp:</span>
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JpLU85h2.png">
    <img src="https://i.sstatic.net/JfXymTp2.png">
  </div>
</body></html>



In Firefox, it's possible to define a different browser default using userContent.css, which is userChrome's lesser-known brother. I don't believe that Chromium browsers have a similar capability.

thank you. Indeed, the images are getting "blurred when zoomed", and they are that by default in my browser due to that everything inside the browser is zoomed for my small 10.2'' sized screen to cope with the content. And the most relevant part for me is this phrase:  "In general, it's up to the web author to specify better CSS.". For my special case, the solution would be to create SVG version of them, because they don't get blurred when zoomed in, instead of choosing a raster pixel-based image like PNG. SVGs don't get blurred when zoomed in.
